# C# How get default gateways (routes) and their metrics from disabled or disconnected network adapters (interfaces)?

Tags: c#, c++, networking, routes, metrics

How get default gateways (routes) and their metrics from disabled or disconnected network adapters (interfaces) ?

same as result using "netsh int ip show address" or "route print" or "netsh interface ip show route", its persistence routes:

also

[image: list gateways]

1. WMI Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration works only for enabled and connected adapters:

`string[] gateways = (string[]) objMO["DefaultIPGateway"]; UInt16[] gatewaysMetrics = (UInt16[]) objMO["GatewayCostMetric"];`

2. Class System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface works for disconnected adatpers but can get only gataways Ips without metrics:

`NetworkInterface nic = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(e => e.Description ==  comboBoxInterface.Text).FirstOrDefault(); var nicProperties = nic.GetIPProperties(); var gateways = nicProperties.GatewayAddresses.Select(x => x.Address.ToString()).ToList();`

3. GetIpForwardTable also gets it only for connected interfaces.

How get it for disconnected interfaces, as in above commands?

Any other ways ?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved using WMI:

```
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT NextHop, Metric1 FROM Win32_IP4RouteTable WHERE Destination='0.0.0.0' AND Metric1<>0 AND InterfaceIndex=" + selectedNetInterfaceIndex);
```

but next question how do it using API ?